# Making a scrollable table with fixed header and fixed sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed-header-tables

I need to always display the header and sidebar indexes, but let the content be scrollable freely x & y ... any solutions to this problem?

I have looked at DataTables jQuery plugin (example: [link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/top_bottom_left_right.html)), but I was wondering if there were any alternatives.